# Pandas: Filter like: "value" in list within Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

For example we have a list of names and hashes of each word in name:

```
data = [
  ['John Doe', ['JN','D0']],
  ['John Mitchel', ['JN','MTL']],
  ....
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'hashes'])
```

Is it possible to filter (search) by single hash value. Another words, find all records with hash '**JN**' for example.

I tried something like:

```
df.hashes[lambda x: 'JN' in x]
```

and even:

```
df['JN' in df.hashes]
```

and no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply`:

```
data = [
  ['John Doe', ['JN','D0']],
  ['John Mitchel', ['JN','MTL']],
  ['John Doe1', ['AA','MTL']]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'hashes'])
print (df)
           name     hashes
0      John Doe   [JN, D0]
1  John Mitchel  [JN, MTL]
2     John Doe1  [AA, MTL]

print (df[df.hashes.apply(lambda x: 'JN' in x)])
           name     hashes
0      John Doe   [JN, D0]
1  John Mitchel  [JN, MTL]
```